# Configure "Live Sass Compiler" (VSCode module)

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code

I tried to configure the module "Live Sass Compiler" to put css files in an other directory than the one with scss files, but either I got errors, or it does nothing.

I made a directory/project to test it.

```
Root : C:\\test_space\\sass_compiler_config
Tree:
+ sass_compiler_config
    + build
    + src
        + modules
            + variables.scss
        + style.scss
```

Here is the test configuration I want to use to check it works:

```
{
    "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap" : false,
    "liveSassCompile.settings.showOutputWindow": true,
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats":[
        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": "/sass_compiler_config/build/styles"
        }
    ],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [ 
        "**/node_modules/**",
        ".vscode/**" 
    ],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.includeItems": [
        "/sass_compiler_config/src/style.scss",
    ],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions"
    ]
}
```

I tried creating a directory named ".vscode" with a file "settings.json" inside and add it to the workspace.
I get this error : This setting can not be applied now. It is applied when you open this folder directly.

I tried putting it in the workspace configuration:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "C:\\test_space\\.vscode"
        },
        {
            "path": "C:\\test_space\\sass_compiler_config"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        {
            "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap" : false,
            "liveSassCompile.settings.showOutputWindow": true,
            "liveSassCompile.settings.formats":[
                {
                    "format": "expanded",
                    "extensionName": ".css",
                    "savePath": "/sass_compiler_config/build/styles"
                }
            ],
            "liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [ 
                "**/node_modules/**",
                ".vscode/**" 
            ],
            "liveSassCompile.settings.includeItems": [
                "/sass_compiler_config/src/style.scss",
            ],
            "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [
                "> 1%",
                "last 2 versions"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

No error, but does nothing.
Could be that my paths are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As I guess;
You want to *Save location in relative from workspace root or your Sass files*, if so;

```
* Default value is null. (null means, it will generate CSS in the location of scss/sass. By The Way, It is null, NOT "null").

* "/" denotes relative to root.

* "~" denotes relative to every sass file. - Complex Scenario.
```

Please check the [documentation](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md)
and this is the [result](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/issues/26)

Answer (score 0):

Go to path: C:\Users\your user\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json

and change there the "liveSassCompile.settings.formats" section

for example:

the parameter : "savePath": "/Python/CSS",

[image]